# Pacemaker installation on Debian 8

Tags: debian, failover, pacemaker

I have Debian 8.2 and I wan to install Pacemaker on it.But when I tried by

```
apt-get install pacemaker
```

It gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pacemaker is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'pacemaker' has no installation candidate
```

I have been searched for many times but did not get anything.
I also tried steps mentioned in https://wiki.debian.org/Debian-HA/ClustersFromScratch but no luck.

I have also tried to build from source but getting

```
configure: error: Version of libqb is too old: v0.13 or greater requried
```

The output of pkg-config is

How can I solve this error ?

What should be the best way to setup failover in Debian jessie?

Can anyone please assist me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Pacemaker is available only for Debian Wheezy and Sid, but you can use
rgmanager.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

add the below to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

(changing the repository to something closer, if applicable)

then run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -t jessie-backports pacemaker
```

That caused pacemaker to install for me, although I've not actually set it up  / tested it yet.

(this should proably be a comment on Rei's answer, but I don't have enough "reputation")

Answer (score -1):

By adding the  jessie-backports repository you can install the package.

Add this line to your /etc/apt/source.list:

```
deb http://your-repo/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

More info on: https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/pacemaker